# 2d display objects rotating 360 degrees in circular (elipse) motion

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I am new at stackoverflow so I hope I am not opening a question that has already been answered somewhere already.
I am trying to achieve this effect of displaying some objects exactly as seen on this video:
[visual example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z3Cnr6P5Xk&ab_channel=noob)
This example is from the game Binding of Isaac.

In order to do so I figured as much as I would have to define a ellipse or circle in c# so that I can place objects on the circle's periferi. I would do this by simply dividing my amount of display objects that we will call n with 360* from here I would simply create n points on the circle and make the display objects rotate along the circles periferi until they reach their destination point, in the meantime I just resize the scale as they move.

My question I need answered to start this though is how I should define the ellipse. I've found tutorials on drawing it but I don't really need the visual representation of the ellipse but rather the code that defines the ellipse so I can move these display objects in a circular/ellipse motion.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the perspective projection of a circle. This is achieved below by defining a circle on the XZ plane (rotation about Y) and viewing it from a vantage point translated in the Y axis a bit.

[image: scr1]

I was able to create a quick sample that mimics this behavior. I had to create a continuously updating form, although my approach was heavy-handed, I could have done it with a `Timer`.

I am using `System.Numerics` to generate the 3D geometry, and apply the rotation and view transformations.

### Code

```
public partial class RunningForm1 : Form
{

    float posAngle;
    Queue<PointF> tail;

    #region Windows API - User32.dll
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WinMessage
    {
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public Message msg;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public uint time;
        public System.Drawing.Point p;
    }

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] // We won't use this maliciously
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool PeekMessage(out WinMessage msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint messageFilterMin, uint messageFilterMax, uint flags);
    #endregion


    public RunningForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Initialize the machine
        posAngle = 0f;
        tail = new Queue<PointF>();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        pictureBox1.Paint += pic_Paint;
        pictureBox1.SizeChanged += pic_SizeChanged;

        MainLoop();
    }

    void UpdateMachine()
    {
        posAngle += 0.002f;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    #region Main Loop
    public void MainLoop()
    {
        // Hook the application's idle event
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle += new EventHandler(OnApplicationIdle);
        //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(TrackForm);
    }

    private void OnApplicationIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (AppStillIdle)
        {
            // Render a frame during idle time (no messages are waiting)
            UpdateMachine();
        }
    }

    private bool AppStillIdle
    {
        get
        {
            WinMessage msg;
            return !PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void pic_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Show FPS counter

        // Draw the machine
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        var s = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height) / 2f;
        var view = Matrix4x4.CreatePerspective(1f, 1f, 1f, 10f);
        view = Matrix4x4.Multiply(view, Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(0, 0.24f, 0));
        var q = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitY, posAngle);
        var pts = new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(s/2, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(s/2, -20f, 0),
            new Vector3(s/2, -20f, -18f),
            new Vector3(s/2, -20f,  18f),
            new Vector3(s/2, -40f,  18f),
            new Vector3(s/2, -40f,  -18f),
            new Vector3(s/2, -20f,  -18f),
            new Vector3(s/2, -20f,  0f),
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < pts.Length; i++)
        {
            pts[i] = Vector3.Transform(pts[i], q);
            pts[i] = Vector3.Transform(pts[i], view);
        }

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(ClientSize.Width / 2f, ClientSize.Height / 2f);

        using (var fill = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray))
        {
            foreach (var pt in tail.Reverse())
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(fill, pt.X - 4, pt.Y - 4, 8, 8);
                fill.Color = Color.FromArgb(Math.Max(0, fill.Color.A-1), fill.Color);
            }
        }

        var px = pts.Select((p) => new PointF(p.X, p.Y)).ToArray();
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(SystemBrushes.ActiveCaption, px);
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, px);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, px[0].X - 4, px[0].Y - 4, 8, 8);

        tail.Enqueue(px[0]);
        while (tail.Count >= 255)
        {
            tail.Dequeue();
        }
    }

}
```

I added a `tail` object that draws a tail for a better motion effect.

Comment: ´Thank you for this. I will try it out later when I am home. I will make sure to mark the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Let center coordinate is `(CX, CY)`, scene half-width is `R`, and vertical contraction (ratio of vertical elipse axis and horizontal one) is `V`. Number of objects is `N`

So you can calculate coordinates of object centers at the circle and make vertical contraction.

```
Angle = 2 * Math.Pi / N + Shift
X[i] = CX + R * Cos(Angle)
Y[i] = CY + V * R * Sin(Angle)
```

where i is object number and Shift is parameter of carousel rotation (in range `0..2*Pi`)

Perhaps for exact positioning you have to add `-ObjWidth/2, -ObjHeight/2` (if you drawing dunction takes left top corner rather than center).

Also to provide proper Z-order you have to draw "back" objects first
according to angle range.

Comment: ´Thank you for this. I will try it out later when I am home. I will make sure to mark the answer if it works.